# XQuery template in MarkLogic doesn't show any values, only attributes (TDE)

Tags: templates, namespaces, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I've created a .xml-file and a template to extract some data, but only the attributes show up.

This is my .xml-testfile:

```
<user id="1234" email="test.user@live.com" password="1234">
<type>Human</type>
<notes>
    <note reference="5432" id="753" xmlns="http://testnamespace.de/note">
        <text>example</text>
        <username>John Doe</username>
        <groups>
            <group id="42">Avengers</group>
            <group id="55">JLA</group>
        </groups>
        <distinctiveTitle>title</distinctiveTitle>
        <personNameInverted>Doe John</personNameInverted>
    </note>
</notes>
```

and here the corresponding template:

```
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";
declare namespace testns = "http://testnamespace.de/note";

let $userNoteTDE:=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" xmlns:testns="http://testnamespace.de/note">
    <context>/user/notes/testns:note</context>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <schema-name>user</schema-name>
            <view-name>notes</view-name>
            <columns>
                <column>
                    <name>reference</name>
                    <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
                    <val>@reference</val>
                    <nullable>true</nullable>
                    <default>""</default>
                </column>
                <column>
                    <name>id</name>
                    <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
                    <val>@id</val>
                    <nullable>true</nullable>
                    <default>""</default>
                </column>
                <column>
                    <name>text</name>
                    <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
                    <val>text</val>
                    <nullable>true</nullable>
                    <default>""</default>
                </column>
                <column>
                    <name>username</name>
                    <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
                    <val>username</val>
                    <nullable>true</nullable>
                    <default>""</default>
                </column>
                <column>
                    <name>distinctiveTitle</name>
                    <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
                    <val>distinctiveTitle</val>
                    <nullable>true</nullable>
                    <default>""</default>
                </column>
                <column>
                    <name>personNameInverted</name>
                    <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
                    <val>personNameInverted</val>
                    <nullable>true</nullable>
                    <default>""</default>
                </column>
            </columns>
        </row>
    </rows>
</template>
```

I changed the context to use the correct (?) path and the namespace (because this part should be nested into another template):

```
<context>/user/notes/testns:note</context>
```

If I check the template with **tde:node-data-extract(fn:doc (*TESTFILE PATH*), $userNoteTDE)** 
I get the following output:

```
    {
"TESTFILE PATH": [
  {
    "row": {
     "schema": "user", 
     "view": "notes", 
     "data": {
      "rownum": "1", 
      "reference": "5432", 
      "id": "753", 
      "text": "", 
      "username": "", 
      "distinctiveTitle": "", 
      "personNameInverted": ""
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 }
```

This shows, that the attributes are displayed correctly, but somehow the values (text, username, distinctiveTitle, personNameInverted) of the elements do not work. 
My guess is, that the values need a more refined path or expression, but I can't find any information.
If I change the **text** value for example to `<val>testns:text</val>` in my template, I get the error: **XDMP-UNBPRFX: (err:XPST0081) Prefix testns has no namespace binding**

So somehow the elements can't use the declared namespace, but the attributes can.

Also I skipped the `<groups>` section in my template, because they would need a context on their own, that shouldn't matter, should it?

Thanks in advance for any helpful insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MarkLogic Support gave me the answer for this problem, so I want to share it here!

(Thanks Chris Hamlin!)

It was indeed a namespace problem. The [MarkLogic Documentation](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_41715) shows that for multiple namespaces "path-namespaces" should be used.

After declaring

`...`

```
    <path-namespaces>
        <path-namespace>
            <prefix>testns</prefix>
            <namespace-uri>http://testnamespace.de/note</namespace-uri>
        </path-namespace>
    </path-namespaces>
```

`...`

between *template* and *context*, and using the **testns** prefix on my elements like **testns:text**, the elements are being correctly displayed!

Comment: Since you figured it out, please mark your answer as "Accepted", so that it's clear this question got a good answer.